# What is the difference between ἐκκλησίας and ἐκκλησίαν?

Tags: greek, declension

I know the root word is *ἐκκλησία*, but I don't understand the declensions.

Comment: Welcome to the Latin site! Your question was migrated here at it fits here much better; despite the name, we also include Ancient Greek. Please create and register an account on this site, too, so that you can interact with others, vote up the answers you like, and accept one of them.

Comment: Wouldn't this be about declension rather than about conjugation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The different forms indicate different *cases*, somewhat like the difference between "he", "him", and "his" in English.

**Ἐκκλησία** is the nominative case, for the subject of the sentence, like "he".

**Ἐκκλησίαν** is the accusative case, for the direct object of the sentence, like "him".

**Ἐκκλησίας** is the genitive case, for the owner or possessor of something, like "his". (It can also be the accusative plural, like "them".)

There are a few others too, like the dative **ἐκκλησίᾳ**, if you're giving something *to* the congregation or doing something *for* the congregation, and an entirely separate set of plural forms, for talking about multiple congregations. The way of deriving all these forms is called the **declension** of the noun.

Comment: This. The sentence that comes to mind is what you hear in weddings: Man, love your woman like Jesus loved the ekklesia. You can see how ekklesia is the object here.

Answer (score 0):

Ἐ is no longer used (the apostrophe in general) so it is just E
Also Εκκλησία is used but Εκκλησίαν is no longer used, it is simplified to Εκκλησία at modern Greek. So accusative case is Εκκλησία as well.
Now about (η)Εκκλησία and (της)Εκκλησίας is just as you say, nominative and genitive cases.

Comment: This is Latin stackexchange, so Ancient Greek is on topic (And usually what is meant when Greek appears). Modern Greek isn't on topic